# Are there flexible pressure sensors for Arduino that can measure forces of at least 600 lbs?

Tags: sensors, project, components

I'm in need of flexible pressure sensors that can read how much force is exerted on someone's foot while running (these sensors would be placed inside the shoe). Since pressure can often be three times the weight of the person, I need something fairly strong. Are there fairly cheap sensors that are available or hacks that could do the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are presumably measuring changing (dynamic) loads, you could consider a piezo electric sensor.

At the simplest, use a piezo element usually sold as a buzzer (make sure you get the plain element with no electronics included, some 'buzzers' also have drive circuitry).
[image: Piezo element]

That will give you a voltage pulse proportional to applied pressure, which might give you the precision that you need, and is very small and light to insert in a shoe.

See [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18048/glowing-pressure-plate) for a similar solution (and the above image!)

Comment: This could be a great method! Thanks for pointing this out, I will need to try this.

Answer (score 1):

Sensors such as you describe are usually called "Load Cell".

At the 600 pound weight, I haven't found any "flexible" load cells. A sensor would have to be quite robust.

Flexible might not be the best answer.

[This load cell page](http://www.futek.com/product.aspx?t=load) has quite a range of load cells, several thousand pounds, also not very inexpensive.

This might be difficult to install in running shoes :

[image]

Comment: ... unless you have big futs.

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully I can find one that's thin enough that I can just cut a small portion out of the shoe. I heard that you can change how sensitive some of these sensors are so that they can measure up to 500 lbs. Check out what Im talking about here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=304657.0